# Draw (2, 3) torus knot on the unwrapped torus surface

Tags: parametric, curves

I have constructed a (2, 3) torus knot using the parametric equation
$$
\eqalignno{x =\,& \left(a + b \cos (qs)\right)\cos (ps)&{\hbox{(1)}}\cr y =\,& \left(a + b\cos (qs)\right)\sin(ps)&{\hbox{(2)}}\cr z =\,& b \sin (qs)&{\hbox{(3)}}}
$$
where 0 ≤s≤ 2π.  $a$ and $b$ are the major and minor radius of the torus. $p$ and $q$ are the integers to be varied to get different kinds of knots. The constructed knot on torus is shown here 
[(2,3) knot side view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCwKd.jpg) and [(2,3) knot top view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoA3T.jpg). I wish to unwrap the virtual torus into a rectangle and plot the same knot on this rectangle. This is similar to the top picture in the link [(3, 4) torus knot on the unwrapped torus surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot#/media/File:(3,_4)_torus_knot.svg), But I wish to do the same for the (2,3) torus knot in Matlab. I don't have an idea how to start with. I am looking for hints or reference links to understand. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, note that the parameter space of the torus in which the knot is embedded is $$(\theta,\varphi) \in [0, 2\pi) \times [0, 2\pi),$$ and the torus itself is embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ as $$(x,y,z) = ((a+b \cos \varphi)\cos \theta, (a+b \cos \varphi) \sin \theta, b \sin \varphi).$$  So the knot corresponds to the choice $(\theta, \varphi) = (ps, qs)$.  This immediately gives us the desired mapping, simply by plotting this as a parametric equation in $(\theta, \varphi) \in [0, 2\pi) \times [0, 2\pi)$; e.g., $$(\theta(s), \varphi(s)) = (ps, qs) \pmod {2\pi}, \quad s \in [0 , 2\pi).$$

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thank you.